# Configure Homebrew to not delete old versions

Tags: homebrew

When I install a package through homebrew, it removes the old versions.

```
$ brew upgrade terraform
  /usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.14: 6 files, 42.4MB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13... (6 files, 120.6MB)
Removing: /Users/vikas/Library/Caches/Homebrew/terraform--0.11.13.mojave.bottle.tar.gz... (25.4MB)
```

How can I disable this so that I can switch back to older versions.

```
$ brew switch [formula] [version]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This behavior can be avoided by setting a variable `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE` in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (or specific to your shell).

Once done, you can check whether it has been applied correctly by:

```
$ brew config | grep HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP: TRUE
$
```

This was introduced in v1.9.0 and has been documented in `man brew` as well, but is easy to miss :)

```
Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will be run for the installed formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae
```

References:
 - https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5654

Comment: This should remove the following: `running `brew cleanup mongocli`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see man brew).`

Answer (score 2):

That looks weird because usually homebrew does not actually delete old versions right away, it usually keeps them so you can switch back later. Except maybe you have been doing `brew cleanup`.

If you have not been removing the older versions, then you have a chance for some older version of your programs to be there inactive. You can simply reactivate those previous versions using `brew switch` to brew older versions. e.g.

```
$ brew info mysql (to get info about the installed versions)
$ brew switch mysql 5.7.21 (to switch to a stable version)
```

Alternatively, you use force like so: e.g.

```
brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

EXCEPT you are using 2.0, then YES, This happens as-of 2.0.0., auto cleanup is default. Use `man brew` and see how to opt-out of this behavior.

Checkout `brew --force` in `man brew`

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am on v2.2.1 This has started happening lately, probably after I upgraded brew :( Let me post a question on their forum. I will update the solution here as well.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm sure `man brew` has the solution.

Anyway, let us know what you get on their forum.

Comment: I think its better to use `brew --force` 
That way hbrew wont check for previous version and would let them be.